# AS3 singleton implementations

Tags: actionscript-3

I have seen so many implementations of singletons around, and i just want a singleton that

1.- instances on the first call
2.- instances only once (duh)

So in performance and lowest memory consumtion, whats the best implementation for this?

Example 1

```
package Singletons
{
    public class someClass
    {
        private static var _instance:someClass;

        public function AlertIcons(e:Blocker):void{}

        public static function get instance():someClass{
            test!=null || (test=new someClass(new Blocker()));
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
class Blocker{}
```

Example2

```
public final class Singleton
{
    private static var _instance:Singleton = new Singleton();

    public function Singleton()
    {
        if (_instance != null)
        {
            throw new Error("Singleton can only be accessed through Singleton.instance");
        }
    }

    public static function get instance():Singleton
    {
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

Example 3

```
package {

    public class SingletonDemo {
        private static var instance:SingletonDemo;
        private static var allowInstantiation:Boolean;

        public static function getInstance():SingletonDemo {
            if (instance == null) {
                allowInstantiation = true;
                instance = new SingletonDemo();
                allowInstantiation = false;
            }
            return instance;
        }

        public function SingletonDemo():void {
            if (!allowInstantiation) {
                 throw new Error("Error: Instantiation failed: Use SingletonDemo.getInstance() instead of new.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

example 2 but with a twist since you should allow new Singleton() to be called at least once and I don't like instantiating things until I need them, thus the first call to instance() actually creates the instance... subsequent calls grab the original.

EDIT: Sowed how it can also allow for if you call

```
var singleton:Singleton = new Singleton();
```

it will work... but all future tries will throw the error and force use of the getInstance() method

```
public final class Singleton{
    private static var _instance:Singleton;

    public function Singleton(){
        if(_instance){
            throw new Error("Singleton... use getInstance()");
        } 
        _instance = this;
    }

    public static function getInstance():Singleton{
        if(!_instance){
            new Singleton();
        } 
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, everything looks pretty good, but whats $_instance = this;$ for?

Comment: if _instance is still null when the constructor is called, the constructor completes and sets the class var _instance to the newly constructed instance (this) that it just created. If you call new Singleton() again, it will throw the error.

Comment: but, don't we get the same behavior without that line? a newly constructed instance the fist time then an error on future tries?

Comment: if you call myvar:Singleton = new Singleton()... without _instance = this in the constructor... you could call it over and over again without error.  However if you rely on getInstance() and change new Singlton() in that method to say _instance = new Singleton()... then getInstance would work perfectly... but calls directly to var = new Singleton() throughout the app would not throw errors until getInstance was called at least once.  The method I showed you protects both getInstance() and new Singleton() from ever generating a second instance.

Comment: its the same net result as example two that you gave, it simply doesn't construct the first Singleton instance until it is actually asked for the first time.

Comment: oh, u're right, i wasnt really paying atention to the evaluation: if(_instance). Now one last question, is it a good idea to allow myvar:Singleton = new Singleton() to be called once (before getInstance)?.

Comment: no... but that way of coding just ENSURES 100% if someone comes behind you in 6 months (or you if you forget :) ) and tries to call new Singleton() or getInstance() they cant break your code either way... it will always force a singleton no matter what anyone tries.