# how to call sub mxml values into main mxml in flex?

Tags: java, apache-flex, mxml, blazeds

Actually in my Flex sample applicaion have Main mxml called `Demo.mxml`..
in the main mxml file have login button when we click login button `Login.mxml` file called

```
protected function button2_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            PopUpManager.createPopUp(this,Login);
        }
```

In Login.mxml file doing some authetication useing java..

```
public var userService:UserService = new UserService();
        [Bindable] public var userVO:UserVO = new UserVO();

        protected function loginUser(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            var rpcAuthenticateUser:AsyncToken = userService.authenticateUser(userid_id.text, password_id.text);
            rpcAuthenticateUser.addResponder(new mx.rpc.Responder(handle_authenticate_success, handler_failure));

        }
........


 userVO=userService.getUser();
......
```

All are done in Login.mxml file correctly Now i am getting value.

```
How to get userVO object in Demo.mxml file ?
```

Actually i'm trying but it give some Null values......Plz help me

```
Thanks in Advance...
```

Comment: Move all remoting logic to one singleton class, so you could get its instance from any point of your application

Comment: Please give me one example for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a model class that is a singleton [See my answer here about making a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318290/as3-singleton-implementations/13318889#13318889).

then in your Demo.mxml

```
[Bindable] public var model:MyModel = MyModel.getInstance();
```

then in your login form

```
public var model:MyModel = MyModel.getInstance();
```

then when you get the response from the service:

```
model.userVO = userService.getUser();
```

now in your Demo.mxml, userVO is now populated and usable there.