# call function AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

```
public function PubliCTest(_arg_1:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("PubliCTestSub" + this.tell.text() + " , " + this.hello.text());
    if (((this.istextValid()) && (this.istextsubValid()))){
        var url:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.nasydbasda.com/tnewabsud.php");
        var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        vars.text1 = this.text1.text();
        vars.textsub = this.textsub.text();
        req.data = vars ;
        req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        url.load(req);
        url.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, reqcompleted);

    }
    this.onSignInSub();
}
```

This is my function, I want to take some functionality from it for use (another function in another class). Basically how do I call this from another class while keeping all the data (functions) from this current class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class methods are bound, they gonna stick to their own **this** object unless you forcibly pass them another one. That means, as long as you can refer this function of yours, you can call it from wherever.

**Solution 1**: [singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318290/as3-singleton-implementations). Assuming you have/need only one instance of the class with that method, you put the reference to the class static variable and can call it as **YourClass.instance.yourMethod(args);**

**Solution 2**: static reference. Basically, the same, with the same assumption there's only one class instance, you can bypass the instance reference and declare a public variable to address the method reference instead. You can call it as **YourClass.MyMethod();**

```
package
{
    public class YourClass
    {
        static public var MyMethod:Function;

        // Class constructor.
        public function YourClass()
        {
            MyMethod = yourMethod;
        }

        public function yourMethod():void
        {
            // ... whatever
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 3**: pass the reference. If you cannot go with singleton(-like) solution because you have several instances, well, then pass the method reference directly through your application architecture. You might want to read about [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).